# Environment variables in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

a lot of paths are required inside vscode: path to git, cmake, llvm (I'm c++ dev), etc. some other than PATH variables are required too.
can't find the setting where I can add this for vscode itself, not for a tasks only. please help with it.

please do not suggest to define these outside of vscode, do not want to do this for some reasons

thank you

Comment: Do you mean on a per-workspace basis? My current work around is to have the env setup in the base makefile (or equivalent build tool).

Comment: the request mostly solved (per-workspace basis) by an author of CMake Tools extension. so that covers my usage scenarios

Answer (score 3):

VSCode 1.15 allows you to specify env variables for the integrated terminal

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_15#_configure-environment-of-terminal-sessions

Inside a VSCode task you can set vars by editing the `tasks.json` in the options section, e.g.

```js
"options": {
    "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "special"
    }
},
```